# disable wsdl list

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat

I'm using sun's **jaxws-ri** on **tomcat6** to publish web-services

There is a Web-Service listing page which lists all wsdls, how can i disable this page ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why would you want to do that ?

Comment: I don't now the internals of jaxws-ri, but you could add a servlet filter to return 404 on the 'disabled' url.